# setText("") not working

Tags: android, android-edittext

Why don't work setText("")? EditText stores last input data and when i call the AlertDialog again, show stored data.

```
case IDD_SET_NAME:
builder=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("Name Title");

EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setText("");//This method not work
builder.setView(input);

   builder.setPositiveButton("Create", onClickListener_DialogResetPin);
   builder.setNeutralButton("Cancel", onClickListener_DialogResetPin);

   // create and show dialog
   dialog = builder.create();
   dialog.show();

    Button btnOK = dialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(onClickListener_btnOK);

    break;
```

Comment: why you set text with empty string?

Comment: Instead of empty EditText what are you getting?

Comment: Try to set some string with - `input.setText("Testing");`

Comment: Post the code of complete class, i.e. who you are showing and dismissing the dialog.

Comment: write the input.setText("");

after builder.setView(input); line

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dialog` is not destroyed if you `dismiss` it. So, if you show it again, it will not be recreated and `input.setText("");` will not run. If you want the `dialog` to be recreated, use `removeDialog()` instead of `dismissDialog()`

Answer (score 0):

You are in onCreateDialog. This is called the first time you show a dialog, only. If you have modifications to perform on your alert, you should do it in onPrepareDialog.

A little debugging and documentation reading would have helped you here.